# Syntax error while running application with uwsgi file directive for sample application

Tags: python

I am trying to run one sample application with uWSGI file directive using two files for it testService.ini(config file) & testService.py (application file).

```
**testService.ini**
 [uwsgi]
 wsgi-file = '/opt/testService/testService.py'
 callable = app

**testService.py**
def application(env, start_response):
start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
return [b"Hello World"]
```

running the above file using : `uwsgi --http :9090 --wsgi-file testService.ini`

```
Output:
Starting uWSGI 2.0.17 (64bit) on [Thu Jun 21 15:52:33 2018]
compiled with version: 5.4.0 20160609 on 14 June 2018 10:09:32
os: Linux-4.13.0-45-generic #50~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 30 11:18:27 UTC 2018
nodename: ubuntu
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 8
current working directory: /opt/testService
detected binary path: /home/jmallick/.local/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 15481
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uWSGI http bound on :9090 fd 4
spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 7848)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:45781 (port auto-assigned) fd 3
Python version: 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18)  [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x824400
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 72920 bytes (71 KB) for 1 cores
Operational MODE: single process
File "testService.ini", line 2
**wsgi-file = '/opt/testService/testService.py'
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
failed to compile python file testService.ini**
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode
uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 7847, cores: 1)
```

And over the browser I am getting "Internal Server Error". Can someone help me understanding what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: also tried to change from wsgi-file = '/opt/testService/testService.py' to wsgi-file = /opt/testService/testService.py. No luck

Comment: did you find its solution? We have a similar kind of issue.